# Fatal Exception on creating table row

Tags: android

I am quite new in android .In my application I have created 3  buttons and some text views and edit texts in a table layout. I want to replace the buttons with a menu.For that I tried to insert a new table row with menu , without removing the buttons.Then it shows Fatal Exception.Again I tried it with replacing the buttons .But Fatal Exception came.I think problem occurs when I insert new table row.What's wrong with my XML file?

Here is my XML File

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#eef1f5"
    android1:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >



    <TableLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >


       <TableRow>
            <menu >
             <item android:id="@+id/bb"

                    android:title="show"/>

             <item android:id="@+id/help"

                    android:title="help" />
           </menu>

         </TableRow>

        <TableRow >   

         <Button
              android:id="@+id/b3 "

              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Connect"
               android:layout_width="0dip" 
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <Button
         android1:id="@+id/b1 "
         android1:layout_width="0dip"
         android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android1:layout_weight="1"
         android1:text="Retrieve Data" />` 
        <Button
           android:id="@+id/b2 "

           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Close" 
           android:layout_width="0dip" 
           android:layout_weight="1"   />

      </TableRow>





   <TableRow>


   <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/systemId"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="SysId"
        android:layout_width="0dip" 
      android:layout_weight="1" >

    </TextView>

     <EditText
           android:id="@+id/systemId1"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
       />
    <TextView 
              android:id="@+id/opMode"

              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="Model"
             android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:layout_weight="1">

     </TextView>

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/opMode1"

          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:enabled="false"
          android:layout_width="0dip" 
          android:layout_weight="1.1"
     />
    <TextView 
             android:id="@+id/DCTime"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DCTimer"
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
             android:layout_weight="1">
     </TextView>

   <EditText
           android:id="@+id/DCTime1"

         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:enabled="false"
          android:layout_width="0dip" 
           android:layout_weight="1.1"
    />      
   </TableRow>        




     </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: what is the fatal exception details?

Comment: `ctrl+shift+f` will align the code properly in both xml and class. Please do it for the above code for easy understanding

Comment: why are u putting menu, what u want to do?

Comment: I just want to replace the button and place a menu instead of them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<menu>` is not a valid child of `<TableRow>`

Comment: sir where should i place a menu then?

Comment: when i place menu under the scroll View i got this Scroll View can have only one child. when i place menu above  scroll bar i got

Comment: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Comment: Menus go in xml files under res/menu/. And are inflated in onCreateOptionsMenu().